# Invalid column name 'Escalation'

Tags: sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm using PyODBC to get data from MS SQL database.

Here is my code:

```
query = ''' 
    select a.created, a.asset_num, a.description, a.resolution, a.type, a.subtype
    from SC_SR_EXPORT_V as a
    where TYPE = "Escalation";
'''
data = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
data.head()
```

I'm getting the following error:

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '
> select a.created, a.asset_num, a.description, a.resolution, a.type, a.subtype
> from SC_SR_EXPORT_V as a
> where TYPE = "Escalation"; ': ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Escalation'. (207)
> (SQLExecDirectW)")

Answer (score 0):

I've changed `where TYPE = "Escalation"` to `where TYPE = 'Escalation'` and it worked.
Apparently, it does not like double-quotes for some reason.